# Android Notifcation issue

Tags: android, android-notifications

What i am trying to implement is NOTIFICATION i.e the alerts using notification manager.
I am asking user to select the date and time and set alert.Set alert has some values like
NONE,On Time,5 mins before,15 mins before,30 mins before and so on..Its working good for every one except NONE..If user select NONE then the NOTIFICATION shouldn't go.But instead it is going straight away.The code which i have done is below.. please do suggest something for it.Since its first option in the list i am not doing anything if user selects none.So i am not setting anything for it.

```
if(alert.equalsIgnoreCase("On Time"))
{
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,reminderday);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,remindermonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,reminderyear);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
    starttime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
else if(alert.equalsIgnoreCase("5 Minutes Before"))
{
    Log.i("inside","5 mins before");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,reminderday);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,remindermonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,reminderyear);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute-5);
    starttime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
}

else if(alert.equalsIgnoreCase("15 Minutes Before"))
{
    Log.i("inside","15 mins before");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,reminderday);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,remindermonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,reminderyear);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute-15);
    starttime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
else if(alert.equalsIgnoreCase("30 Minutes Before"))
{
    Log.i("inside","30 mins before");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,reminderday);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,remindermonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,reminderyear);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute-30);
    starttime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
else if(alert.equalsIgnoreCase("1 Hour Before"))
{
    Log.i("inside","1 hr before");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,reminderday);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,remindermonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,reminderyear);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour-1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
    starttime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
else if(alert.equalsIgnoreCase("2 Hour Before"))
{
    Log.i("inside","2 hr before");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,reminderday);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,remindermonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,reminderyear);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour-2);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
    starttime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
else if(alert.equalsIgnoreCase("1 Day Before"))
{
    Log.i("inside","1 day before");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,reminderday-1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,remindermonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,reminderyear);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
    starttime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
else if(alert.equalsIgnoreCase("2 Day Before"))
{
    Log.i("inside","2 day before");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,reminderday-2);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,remindermonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,reminderyear);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
    starttime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
else if(alert.equalsIgnoreCase("1 Week Before"))
{
    Log.i("inside","1 week before");
    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,reminderday-7);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,remindermonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,reminderyear);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);
    starttime=cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
else
        {
            starttime=-1;   
        }
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,starttime, pendingIntent);
```

The problem i got is that since the starttime value would be 0 if it for none.
So what value i should set for starttime so that it doesnt go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (starttime > 0){    
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,starttime, pendingIntent);    
}
```

Use the above code instead.